# ¿Como transformar una consulta de api guardado con ElasticSearch en una variable de texto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

Quiero transformar el resultado siguiente de una consulta en una API guardado con ElasticSearch en un texto para utilisarlo luego.

```
b'{"BTC":{"USD":2403.99},"ETH":{"USD":222.1},"DASH":{"USD":179.04}}'
b'{"BTC":{"USD":2402.89},"ETH":{"USD":222.1},"DASH":{"USD":179.04}}'
...
```

Quiero obtenerlo en una variable :

```
json_text = """
[
{"BTC":{"USD":2403.99},"ETH":{"USD":222.1},"DASH":{"USD":179.04}},
{"BTC":{"USD":2402.89},"ETH":{"USD":222.1},"DASH":{"USD":179.04}}
]
"""
```

En efecto me serivra en la dataframe siguiente para calculacion finenciera :

```
a = json.loads(json_text)

values = [(each["BTC"].get("USD"), each["ETH"].get("USD"), each["DASH"].get("USD")) for each in a]
```

Sin embargo, si tienen un enfoque distinto, por supuesto estoy interesado en escucharlas

#### producción del output y intento de salvaguardia

Aqui fue como producía el output y intento guardarlo en un fichero de texto con la buena forma.
En el fichero `Main.py`, llamo a una clase Util con `ut = Util`

En esta clase intento transformar el resultado en un texto :

```
import threading
from Elastic import Elastic
import urllib.request
from ValueAnalyse import ValueAnalyse 
class Util:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def disp(self,el,call,prices,assets):
        threading.Timer(1, self.disp,[el,call,prices,assets]).start()
        value = urllib.request.urlopen(call).read()
        prices.append(value)
        print(len(prices))
        print("prices : ")
        print(type(prices))
        a = " ".join(str(x) for x in prices)
        print(a)
        va = ValueAnalyse(a)
        el.store(assets,value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que muestras tu entrada, por el uso del literal [`b'`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)  pareciera ser uno o más objetos tipo `Bytes` recibidos luego de la invocación de un API, y lo que deseas es transformar todos en una cadena JSON válida que pueda ser interpretada y convertida a un diccionario. En caso que estos objetos los tuvieras en una lista, por ejemplo así:

```
elastic_data = [b'{"BTC":{"USD":2403.99},"ETH":{"USD":222.1},"DASH":{"USD":179.04}}',
                b'{"BTC":{"USD":2402.89},"ETH":{"USD":222.1},"DASH":{"USD":179.04}}'
                ]
```

Para convertir todo en una sola cadena JSON, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
json_text = "[" + ','.join([e.decode("utf-8") for e in elastic_data]) + ']'
```

Es decir:

- transformar cada `Bytes`en un `String` usando la codificación adecuada, a modo de ejemplo usamos `utf-8` pero eso habría que consultarlo en la documentación de la API
- Concatenamos todos los elementos agregando una `,` para separarlos
- Concatenamos apertura y cierre de la lista `[` y `]`

Tal como quedó la variable `json_text` es válida para importarla

```
import json
a = json.loads(json_text)
values = [(each["BTC"].get("USD"), each["ETH"].get("USD"), each["DASH"].get("USD")) for each in a]
print(values)
```

La salida:

```
[(2403.99, 222.1, 179.04), (2402.89, 222.1, 179.04)]
```

Espero te sea útil

Comment: Muchas gracias para su respuesta, sin embargo me contesto el terminal que `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes` porque le da su comando `[{'BTC': {'USD': 2135.41}, 'ETH': {'USD': 175}, 'DASH': {'USD': 145.32}}]` por ejemplo que no esta formateado como JSON.